# Angular 2 : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

I am getting the following error on browser console after clicking on Submit button.

[image]

In this application I am trying to get information about the Student uploaded code below.
I am unable to find why this error is shown on console.
**I have correctly added the formControlName.**

1. Component

   ```
           import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
           import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

           @Component({
             selector: 'app-new-record',
             templateUrl: './new-record.component.html',
             styleUrls: ['./new-record.component.css']
           })
           export class NewRecordComponent implements OnInit {
             myFormGroup: FormGroup;
             constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
               this.myFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
                 name: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
                   Validators.required
                 ])),
                 claz: new FormControl('BCA'),
                 admissionYear: new FormControl(Validators.compose([Validators.required]))
               });
             }

             ngOnInit() {

             }

             onSubmit(student) {
               console.log('onSubmit called !');
             }

           }
   ```

   2. Template

      ```
          <form [formGroup]="myFormGroup"
          (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="claz">Class:</label> <select name="claz" formControlName="claz">
                      <option value="MCA">MCA</option>
                      <option value="BCA">BCA</option>
                      <option value="M.Sc">M.Sc</option>
                      <option value="B.Tech">B.Tech</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">Name:</label> <input type="text"
                      class="form-control" id="name" formControlName="name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="admissionYear">Admission Year:</label> <input type="number"
                      class="form-control" id="admissionYear" formControlName="admissionYear">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Submit</button>
          </form>
      ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `form` defined, instead use `myFormGroup` which has been defined as `formGroup`

```
(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myFormGroup.value)"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I wasted 5 hours to resolve this. I would have asked this question earlier.

Comment: @TusharGirase np, that happens with dev. Glad to hear it helped, Thanks :)